# How could I cut string strings by words according to a length?

Tags: java

How can I cut a string string by words according to a length

```
String text = "Hello world welcome";
```

The maximum size of a row must be 15 characters, if you used the substring method I would stay like this

```
Hello wordl wel
come
```

and it should not be like that, it should be like that

```
Hello wordl
welcome
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm trying to cut a string, but by words not by characters, you understand me ?

Comment: @AndresFelipePinzonBaldion could you post some of your code so that we can take a look at what you've tried and get a better understanding of what you're trying to do?

Comment: If no attempt has been made yet, then this sounds like a great exercise to grab a piece of paper or a whiteboard and write down a logic flow, then verify it by writing the code.

Comment: *I'm trying to cut a string, but by words not by characters,*-how?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_wrap_and_word_wrap#Algorithm

Comment: For the record, this is called "word wrapping".

Answer (score 2):

Use [Apache Commons Text](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) [`WordUtils.wrap()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/WordUtils.html#wrap(java.lang.String,int)) method:

```
String out = WordUtils.wrap("Hello world welcome", 15);
System.out.println(out);
```

will output:

```
Hello world
welcome
```